# Create HTML partials with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

My goal is to generate HTML partials. From the following template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Into this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/some-public-path/css/styles.1234abcd.css">
```

My initial thought was that this could probably be accomplished by disabling the `inject` feature of `HtmlWepbackPlugin`:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, 'input-file.html'),
  filename: 'output-file.html',
  inject: false,
}),
```

Though it does create the correct output **file** and `link` tag, I'm finding myself clueless as to how I am to create/link to the hashed `styles.css` file.

So the question is, using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, is it possible to create a HTML partial which references (using e.g. `link`) a hashed resource?